# how to print dictionary key in the even frequency order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like print out dictionary key, value pair in the even frequency like

> a = dict('A': 3, 'B': 5}
>   => ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
>
> a = dict('A': 4, 'B': 1}
>   => ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A']

I know I can use a while loop to print each key and remove the count every time until all value from all key is 0 but if there is better way to do it?

```py
    def func(d: dict):
        res = []
        while any(i > 0 for i in d.values()):
            for k, c in d.items():
                if c > 0:
                    res.append(k)
                    d[k] -= 1
        return res
```

Comment: Please show your current attempt. Are you using a version of Python >= 3.6?

Comment: sure, updated the questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm assuming you're using a version of Python that guarantees the iteration order of dictionaries)

Here's an itertools-y approach. It creates a generator for each letter that yields the letter the given number of times, and it combines all of them together with `zip_longest` so they get yielded evenly.

```
from itertools import repeat, zip_longest

def iterate_evenly(d):
    generators = [repeat(k, v) for k,v in d.items()]
    exhausted = object()
    for round in zip_longest(*generators, fillvalue=exhausted):
        for x in round:
            if x is not exhausted:
                yield x


print(list(iterate_evenly({"A": 3, "B": 5})))
print(list(iterate_evenly({"A": 4, "B": 1})))
```

Result:

```
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

You can do the same thing in fewer lines, although it becomes harder to read.

```
from itertools import repeat, zip_longest

def iterate_evenly(d):
    exhausted = object()
    return [x for round in zip_longest(*(repeat(k, v) for k,v in d.items()), fillvalue=exhausted) for x in round if x is not exhausted]

print(iterate_evenly({"A": 3, "B": 5}))
print(iterate_evenly({"A": 4, "B": 1}))
```

Answer (score 2):

For a one-liner.

First, create a list with two elements: a list of `A`s and a list of `B`s:

```
>>> d = {'A': 3, 'B': 5}
>>> [[k]*v for k, v in d.items()]
[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']]
```

`[k]*v` means: a list with `v` `k`s. Second, interleave `A`s and `B`. We need `zip_longest` because `zip` would stop after the end of the first list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.zip_longest(*[[k]*v for k, v in d.items()]))
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'B'), (None, 'B'), (None, 'B')]
```

Now, just flatten the list and remove `None` values:

```
>>> [v for vs in itertools.zip_longest(*[[k]*v for k, v in d.items()]) for v in vs if v is not None]
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

Other example:

```
>>> d = {'A': 4, 'B': 1}
>>> [v for vs in itertools.zip_longest(*[[k]*v for k, v in d.items()]) for v in vs if v is not None]
['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `sum` with a generator comprehension:

```
res = sum(([key]*value for key, value in d.items()), [])
```

This exploits the fact that `sum` can "add" anything that can use the `+` operators, like lists, in addition to sequence multiplication (`"A"*4 == "AAAA"`).

If you want the order to be randomized, use the `random` module:

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(res)
```

---

If, as Thierry Lathuille notes, you want to cycle through the values in the original order, you can use some itertools magic:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest
res = [*filter(
    bool,  # drop Nones
    chain(*zip_longest(
        *([key]*val for key, val in d.items()))
    )
)]
```

Comment: Though it isn't clearly stated in the question, I think that the OP wants to cycle through the values in the order they are given in the original dict.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the replication & `zip_longest` approach, let's try to simplify the OP's original code:

```
def function(dictionary):
    result = []

    while dictionary:
        result.extend(dictionary)
        dictionary = {k: v - 1 for k, v in dictionary.items() if v > 1}

    return result

print(function({'A': 3, 'B': 5}))
print(function({'A': 4, 'B': 1}))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A']
%
```

Although it might look otherwise, it's *not* destructive on the dictionary argument, unlike the OP's original code.

Comment: that is smart move

Answer (score 0):

It could also be done using a sort of the (position,character) tuples formed by expanding each dictionary entry:

```
a = {'A': 3, 'B': 5}
result = [c for _,c in sorted( (p,c) for c,n in a.items() for p,c in enumerate(c*n))]
print(result) # ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

If the dictionary's order is usable, you can forgo the sort and use this:

```
result = [c for i in range(max(a.values())) for c,n in a.items() if i<n]
```